# VSC Extension – Can't load text file using relative path in extension.ts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write an extension that, when invoked using encloseTag command, shows a list of preset tags loaded from a text file and encapsulates selected text in that tag. I got it to work, but only if I specify a static path – using relative path doesn't work, I get these errors instead:

```
Error reading tags file: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tags.txt'
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.enclosingtags' failed: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\username\ProjectPublisher\out\FILENAME'.
```

When I tried printing the working directory, it was nowhere near the project directory (it was in AppData instead of the project location in the User folder). I am not sure how I can influence this or if this is issue with VSC or my code.
**Note:** I am executing it using debug from VSC (by pressing F5).

How can I get this code to use the tags file from the same dir as the extension.ts file?

`package.json`:

```
(…)
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "encloseTag",
        "title": "Enclose in Tag"
      }
    ]
},
(…)
```

extension.ts:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('encloseTag', () => {

        let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!editor) {
            vscode.window.showErrorMessage('No active text editor');
            return;
        }
        let selection = editor.selection;
        let text = editor.document.getText(selection);
        if (!text) {
            return;
        }

        let tags: string[] = [];
        try {
            let data = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\username\\ProjectPublisher\\tags.txt', 'utf8');
            // Split the data into lines and remove leading and trailing whitespace and newline characters from each line
            tags = data.split('\n').map(line => line.trim().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''));
        } catch (error: any) {
            vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Error reading tags file: ' + error.message);
            return;
        }

        // Prompt the user to select a tag
        vscode.window.showQuickPick(tags).then((tag) => {
            if (!tag) {
                return;
            }

            // Enclose the selected text in the chosen tag
            let newText = `<${tag}>${text}</${tag}>`;
            editor.edit(edit => {
                edit.replace(selection, newText);
            });
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);

    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\FILENAME`);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

`tags.txt`:

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
```

input:
This is some text to annotate.

output:
This is some text to annotate.

Comment: construct an absolute path using the file path in the context (argument of activate function)

Comment: @rioV8 you mean something like `let extensionPath = context.extensionPath;` and `let tagsFilename = path.resolve(extensionPath, 'tags.txt');`?

Comment: Ok this actually worked, thanks. If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

construct an absolute path using the file path in the context (argument of activate function)

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)
```

The absolute file path of the directory containing the extension

```
ExtensionContext::extensionPath
```